# jQuery Ajax - json datatype, send more than 1 parameter?

Tags: php, ajax

I have the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/articles/moveArticle/' + article.id,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
    console.log(result);
         //something
    },
    error: function (result) {
    }
});
```

The php function that gets called by the ajax is:

```
function moveArticle ($articleId) {
  // move it
}
```

This works great but how do I send more than 1 parameter?

Comment: You must have some kind of framework in between that translates the ajax call to a function call. Otherwise you'd never end up with a nice argument for your function (you would have to obtain it from $_GET). Might be best if you provide that info as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the function `moveArticle`, I guess you use some php framework.
Without knowing which one - it is impossible to answer.
From the structure of the function - i assume that it uses routing - so it's not a POST request (that is why i ignored the use of `data` as others mentioned).

So, my best guess is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/articles/moveArticle/' + article.id + '/' + anotherParameter,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
    console.log(result);
         //something
    },
    error: function (result) {
    }
});


function moveArticle ($articleId, $theOtherParameter) {
  // move it
}
```

Comment: You can omit `type: 'POST'` as ajax uses `GET` by default.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an object and then pass it in the data property of ajax call using `JSON.stringify(data)`

```
var data ={
    id : article.id,
    name : article.name // other parameters
} 

$.ajax({
    url: '/articles/moveArticle',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data = JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function(result) {
    console.log(result);
         //something
    },
    error: function (result) {
    }
});
```

Comment: This is an incorrect answer for 2 reasons. It is incorrectly formatted because of the "=" sign and also jQuery does stringify an object by default, there is no need to call JSON.stringify, just pass an object to it as in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `data` parameter in your ajax call.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

**EDIT**

As I read other answers I have decided to enhance my answer.

`dataType` parameter as stated in jQuery documentation stands for:

> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.

Which means you are expecting JSON data from the server. If you set `dataType` to json it does NOT mean you are sending a JSON object to the server.

There is a parameter in ajax call that you have set, it is `type`. This parameter states how you are going to send the `data` to server. You have used a `POST` method. It means that anything set in the `data` is accessible by PHP from the `$_POST` array

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/articles/moveArticle/' + article.id,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        something: 'Something that can be accessed by PHP as $_POST["something"]',
    },
    success: function(result) {
    console.log(result);
         //something
    },
    error: function (result) {
    }
});
```